# html table is duplicating defaultValue's for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have some data that is displayed in a table. When I add a table data cell (td) with JS the defaultValue and innerText of the previous table data cell (td) is being copied in the new table data (td). I don't understand why this happens? I just add a new html element which, in essence, has nothing to do with the already existing element I would say.

```
 const [dataSet, setDataSet] = useState([
{
  City: "Amsterdam",
  Provence: "North-Holland"
},
{
  City: "Rotterdam",
  Provence: "South-Holland"
}
]);
    
  const newCity = () => {
    const city = [
      {
        City: "Groningen",
        Provence: "Groningen"
      }
    ];

    setDataSet(city);
  };
<button onClick={newCity}>Add city</button>

<table>
 <tr>
  <th>City</th>
  <th>Provence</th>
 </tr>
 {dataSet.map(city => (
  <tr>
   <td>
     <input defaultValue={city.City}/>
   </td>
   <td>
    <input defaultValue={city.Provence}/>
   </td>
 </tr>
 )}
</table>
```

So when I click on the 'newCity button' a new table row (tr) is added, but instead of populating the table data cells (td) with the correct data (City: 'Groningen', Provence: 'Groningen') it populates the td with the data from the previous table row (tr) (City: 'Amsterdam', Provence: 'North-Holland'). This seems really odd to me, since I only add a new html element that has no relation to the table row (tr) before it exempt for it being in the same table.

Here is a codebox link to see the behavior in action:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-water-rss2m8?file=/src/App.js

Why does it behave like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important things to take into consideration here.

First, your program is outputting a warning:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

**Always** deal with warnings. They are there for a reason!

Second, you are dealing with a *default* (as opposed to *current*) value.

---

When you replace the array with a new array, React generates new JSX and compares it to the existing DOM.

The *first* row has the same (lack of) key so it changes the default values of the existing row. (The *second* row no longer exists so it removes it).

Changing the default values doesn't have any effect through: The inputs *already* have values, which they continue to display.

---

You could give the generated rows keys:

```
<tr key={something}>
```

… but you will need to figure out what the something is.

You might use the city name, but it seems like that is a piece of data which might change — so changing the city name would make it look like a new row and not an update to an existing row.

You might consider using the [uuid module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate a unique ID when the object is created.

---

You could also make the inputs [*controlled*](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) by passing them values instead of default values. This would require that you update the value you pass to them as they are edited.

Comment: Hi Quentin, the product is still in production so I ignored the warnings for now. It never gave me any issues until now, but I guess I should have to at least tried to resolve them when this issue came around. Thanks for the help. Adding a key did the trick. The problem with the cities above is a duplicatable version on the the issue I was facing. In reality the data is coming from a database with a unique id (provided by uuid indeed), so setting a key was no issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a key on the item

```
{dataSet.map((city) => (
          <tr key={city.City}>
```

...
etc

Comment: I was lazy in dealing with the warnings, but I shouldn't have I see now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because you are working with uncontrolled components.

If you want your input values to reflect state changes you need to use the value and not the defaultValue, and you also probably want to have an onChange handler.

```
<input value={city.City} />
```

Comment: The input values are coming from a database in the real world problem. I used an example that is duplicatable so that you guys go see the problem without having to connect a database. So the component uses a defaultValue to show the input form the database. In the real problem there is a onChange for users to change the value. I didn't think the onChange was relevant to the problem, so I omitted it here.

Answer (score -1):

First, the native Input element doesn't have defaultValue attribute. Look at the attributes list in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). It has only value and placeholder.

Secondly, if you want to add new city to the dataSet, you must merge the city-object to the array, not replace it.

```
setDataSet(currentDataSet => {
  return [...currentDataSet, city]
})
```

Comment: This isn't a native input element, it is a React input Component (which *does* have a `defaultValue` prop).

Comment: Oh, and the native Input DOM element has it too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#properties